# How can I start the Flink job manager web interface when running Flink from an IDE

Tags: apache-flink

I would like to access the Flink Web interface when starting it locally from the IDE.

I need this because I'd like to access the counters (accumulators) of Flink.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Flink new versions `ConfigConstants.LOCAL_START_WEBSERVER` is deprecated, Instead you can use the following,

```
StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.createLocalEnvironmentWithWebUI(new Configuration());
```

Also don't forget to add the ***flink-runtime-web*** dependency.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
        <artifactId>flink-runtime-web</artifactId>
        <version>${flink.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 18):

In order to start the web interface when starting Flink locally, we have to enable the web interface in the `FlinkMiniCluster`. The `FlinkMiniCluster` is the class managing the startup of all Flink services locally.

Include the dependency:

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
  <artifactId>flink-runtime-web_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
  <version>${flink.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

The following snippet will enable the web interface for a `StreamExecutionEnvironment`:

```java
// set up the execution environment
Configuration conf = new Configuration();
conf.setBoolean(ConfigConstants.LOCAL_START_WEBSERVER, true);
final StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.createLocalEnvironment(8, conf);
```

You can also use [RestOptions](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-master/api/java/org/apache/flink/configuration/RestOptions.html) to configure the server:

```java
conf.setInteger(RestOptions.PORT, 8082);
```

Comment: http://apache-flink-user-mailing-list-archive.2336050.n4.nabble.com/Can-t-access-Flink-Dashboard-at-8081-running-Flink-program-using-Eclipse-td8016.html

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the code in the above answer, the following dependency is also required in the pom file.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
        <artifactId>flink-runtime-web_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
        <version>${flink.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```