# How to use command line interface and visit web-front when Flink running in JVM

Tags: apache-flink

I use IntelliJ for development and it seems that if I click `run` on IntelliJ, Flink is running in JVM. In this case, how can I visit its Web Interface or using the command line interface?

The reason is that I need to execute some command to shut down my Flink progress gracefully based on Job Id and one good way to do this is from command-line interface. BUT I don't know how to access it. (like where can I find ./bin/start-webclient.sh and how can I visit localhost:8081 which is default web front?)

Comment: The answer here -- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35138538/how-can-i-start-the-flink-job-manager-web-interface-when-running-flink-from-an-i -- answers part of your question.

Comment: Thanks that helps