# Flink REST Monitor API

Tags: apache-flink

After reading from this documentation: https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.2/monitoring/rest_api.html, I know that I can send a POST Request to start a Flink job from a savepoint.

The problem is that: This REST interface is hosted in JobManager, which is only alive if there is a job already running there (I run this locally in a JVM). So this is a contradiction because if I want to start a job, there is no job already running right?

Anyone have any clues?

Answer (score 0):

Flink's monitoring API web server and the web dashboard web server are currently the same and run together at the same port. This means that [these instructions for how to start up the web UI from inside an IDE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35138538/how-can-i-start-the-flink-job-manager-web-interface-when-running-flink-from-an-i/35138539#35138539) should do the job.