# Cannot launch flink from local host when trying to run it with webUI

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I'm trying to debug my flink from intellij using the flink UI.
the problem it somethims doesn't launched throwing java.net.BindException: Could not start rest endpoint on any port in port range 8081

my piece of code that should let the flink ui run (from windows) is:

```
  String osName = System.getProperty("os.name");
  if (osName.toLowerCase().contains("win")) {
     Configuration conf = new Configuration();
     conf.setBoolean(ConfigConstants.LOCAL_START_WEBSERVER, true);
     env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.createLocalEnvironmentWithWebUI(conf);
  } else {
     env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
  }
```

can you assist please?

Comment: Follow these two threads: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46988499/flink-webui-when-running-from-ide/47000955#47000955 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35138538/how-can-i-start-the-flink-job-manager-web-interface-when-running-flink-from-an-i

Comment: why you checking os name??

Answer (score 3):

If you cannot bind to a given network port that usually means it has been already taken. So check if there is any process running on that port (old job manager?) and kill it.

Alternatively, you can change the port with

```
conf.setInteger(RestOptions.PORT, 8082);
```

or if want to be on the save side specify a range

```
conf.setString(RestOptions.BIND_PORT, "8081-8099");
```

Answer (score 1):

One can change the default port mapping in `../conf/flink-conf.yml` file.

```
rest.port: 18081
```

or use port range e.g.

```
rest.bind-port: 18080-18090
```