# Flink: Error while starting scala-shell - Could not create the DispatcherResourceManagerComponent

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am using Flink version 1.10.0 and while starting the Scala shell using '**start-scala-shell.sh**', it throws an exception as follows:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.flink.util.FlinkException: Could not create the DispatcherResourceManagerComponent.
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.component.DefaultDispatcherResourceManagerComponentFactory.create(DefaultDispatcherResourceManagerComponentFactory.java:261)
```

I've changed the rest-port from 8081 to 8089, but still facing the same issue.

I even tried this with Flink 1.9.2, but faced the same issue.

[image]

Kindly help!

Comment: Have you checked that these ports are available on your machine? If not I'd recommend to use a [big port range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58898543/cannot-launch-flink-from-local-host-when-trying-to-run-it-with-webui/58957258#58957258) to see if that could be an issue.